# How to iterate a Pytest test with fixture which does setup and teardown

Tags: pytest, fixtures

I am very new to pytest.

There is a test_conf dir which has several test config files.

- ```
  test_conf
  ```
- ```
          test_conf1
  ```
- ```
          test_conf2
  ```

Here is my test function.

conf_files function gets all test_conf files from that dir and returns a list.

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize('test_conf', conf_files())
def test_performance_scenario_1(fixture1, test_conf):
    do_some_thing(test_conf)
```

The fixture1 does setup and teardown for this test.

My proposal is for each test conf file from test_conf, we run test function to do some test against it.

My question is how to pass each element of test_conf to fixture1, since I need to do some initialization in fixture1 setup step which needs the test conf file.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is [parameterised fixtures](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/fixture.html#parametrizing-fixtures). So instead of passing the conf files to your test, you pass it to the fixture, which does the setup/teardown with the particular conf file.

definition of your `fixture1`:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="module", params=conf_files())
def fixture1(request):
    # The pytest fixture `request` gives you access to the params defined in the annotation.
    conf_file = request.param
    # setup / teardown logic
    ...
```

Then in your test, it suffices to only pass the fixture:

```
def test_performance_scenario_1(fixture1):
    # do_some_things
```

Comment: Hi, once fixture1 does setup with test_conf_1, and we still want to use this conf file in test_performance_scenario_1, how to implement it? yield it in fixture1?